# Compress methods and get the data into a One Hot Encoding Matrix

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, one-hot-encoding

My data frame includes a purchase. A buyer (`buyer_id`) can buy several items (`item_id`).
I split the data with `splitter()` and put it into a dok matrix `generate_matrix()`. Then I enter this data in method `get_train_samples()` and then get my `x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train` and `y_test`.

How can I compress this code?
And how can I combine `generate_matrix()` and `get_train_samples()` and enter them in a 'real' one hot encoding matrix?

**Dataframe**:

```
d = {'purchaseid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9],
     'itemid': [ 3, 8, 2, 10, 3, 10, 4, 12, 3, 12, 3, 4, 8, 6, 3, 0, 5, 12, 9, 9, 13, 1, 7, 11, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   purchaseid  itemid
0           0       3
1           0       8
2           0       2
3           1      10
4           2       3
```

**Code**:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sp


PERCENTAGE_SPLIT = 20
NUM_NEGATIVES = 4
def splitter(df):
  df_ = pd.DataFrame()
  sum_purchase = df['purchaseid'].nunique()
  amount = round((sum_purchase / 100) * PERCENTAGE_SPLIT)

  random_list = random.sample(df['purchaseid'].unique().tolist(), amount)
  df_ = df.loc[df['purchaseid'].isin(random_list)]
  df_reduced = df.loc[~df['purchaseid'].isin(random_list)]
  return [df_reduced, df_]

def generate_matrix(df_main, dataframe, name):
  
  mat = sp.dok_matrix((df_main.shape[0], len(df_main['itemid'].unique())), dtype=np.float32)
  for purchaseid, itemid in zip(dataframe['purchaseid'], dataframe['itemid']):
    mat[purchaseid, itemid] = 1.0

  return mat

dfs = splitter(df)
df_tr = dfs[0].copy(deep=True)
df_val = dfs[1].copy(deep=True)

train_mat = generate_matrix(df, df_tr, 'train')
val_mat = generate_matrix(df, df_val, 'val')

def get_train_samples(train_mat, num_negatives):
    user_input, item_input, labels = [], [], []
    num_user, num_item = train_mat.shape
    for (u, i) in train_mat.keys():
        user_input.append(u)
        item_input.append(i)
        labels.append(1)
        # negative instances
        for t in range(num_negatives):
            j = np.random.randint(num_item)
            while (u, j) in train_mat.keys():
                j = np.random.randint(num_item)
            user_input.append(u)
            item_input.append(j)
            labels.append(0)
    return user_input, item_input, labels

num_users, num_items = train_mat.shape

model = get_model(num_users, num_items, ...)

user_input, item_input, labels = get_train_samples(train_mat, NUM_NEGATIVES)
val_user_input, val_item_input, val_labels = get_train_samples(val_mat, NUM_NEGATIVES)
```

What I need

- `user_input`
- `item_input`
- `labels`
- `val_user_input`
- `val_item_input`
- `val_labels`
- `num_users`

Comment: What do you mean by 'real' one hot encoding matrix?

Comment: I think I described it badly. As you can see, it's not like the One Hot Encoding scheme. So I would like to rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty vague what kind of one hot encoding matrix you are looking for. From `get_train_samples`, it seems you don't really need the sparse matrix for model training at the end of the day. Besides, I'm not sure how you are going to one-hot encode observations with three variables `(user_id,item_id,purchased or not)`

As for the problem of combining `generate_matrix` with `get_train_samples`, it is pretty simple,

```
def generate_matrix(df_main,df,num_negatives):
    
    n_samples,n_classes = df_main.shape[0],df_main['itemid'].nunique()
    mat = sp.dok_matrix((n_samples,n_classes), dtype=np.float32)

    user_input,item_input,labels = [],[],[]
    for purchaseid,itemid in zip(df['purchaseid'],df['itemid']):
        
        mat[purchaseid,itemid] = 1.0
        # the data with label 0 in OP's original code 
        fake_items = np.random.choice(a=np.setdiff1d(range(n_classes),itemid),size=num_negatives)
        # label the fake labels with -1.0
        mat[np.repeat(purchaseid,num_negatives),fake_items] = -1.0
        
        # the three lists
        user_input.extend([purchaseid]*(num_negatives+1))
        item_input.append(itemid);item_input.extend(fake_items.tolist())
        labels.append(1.0);labels.extend(np.zeros(num_negatives).tolist())
        
    return mat,user_input,item_input,labels
```

as you can see, in my `generate_matrix`, the fake samples (items not purchased by a user) is encoded with `-1.0` in the sparse matrix. Besides, I use a pretty compact way `fake_items = np.random.choice(a=np.setdiff1d(range(n_classes),itemid),size=num_negatives)` to generate the fake `itemid` as compared to the `while` loop in your code.

With this function, you can run

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sp


d = {'purchaseid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9],
     'itemid': [ 3, 8, 2, 10, 3, 10, 4, 12, 3, 12, 3, 4, 8, 6, 3, 0, 5, 12, 9, 9, 13, 1, 7, 11, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

PERCENTAGE_SPLIT = 20
NUM_NEGATIVES = 4

def splitter(df):
    
    df_ = pd.DataFrame()
    sum_purchase = df['purchaseid'].nunique()
    amount = round(sum_purchase*(PERCENTAGE_SPLIT/100))
    random_list = random.sample(df['purchaseid'].unique().tolist(),amount)
    df_ = df.loc[df['purchaseid'].isin(random_list)]
    df_reduced = df.loc[~df['purchaseid'].isin(random_list)]
    
    return [df_reduced, df_]

dfs = splitter(df)
df_tr = dfs[0].copy(deep=True)
df_val = dfs[1].copy(deep=True)

train_mat,user_input_t,item_id_t,labels_t = generate_matrix(df, df_tr, NUM_NEGATIVES)
val_mat,user_input_v,item_id_v,labels_v = generate_matrix(df, df_val, NUM_NEGATIVES)
```

You will see by running this code, the length of `train_mat.keys()` can be different from the length of `user_input_t`. This is because the same items can be chosen multiple times in `fake_items = np.random.choice(a=np.setdiff1d(range(n_classes),itemid),size=num_negatives)`. If you want to keep the two lengths to be the same, you need to set `replacement=False` in `fake_items = np.random.choice(a=np.setdiff1d(range(n_classes),itemid),size=num_negatives)`.